# Fixed-wing UAV simulation?

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Are there any models of fixed-wing UAVs? I'd like to be able to simulate one and control it through ROS. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hX41rNglX0) video seems promising, but I can't seem to locate anything else about it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8084/fixed-wing-uav-simulation?/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/954/tom-moore/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2015-03-04**:
Maybe asking in the gazebo mailing list is a good option for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think this is [world file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/0bdf41440b657548bd0cabdf5d4e98b36b253194/worlds/twin_rotor_demo.world?at=default), and this is the [plugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/0bdf41440b657548bd0cabdf5d4e98b36b253194/plugins/LiftDragPlugin.hh?at=default).

This is very experimental, and just a proof of concept. I haven't seen other fixed wing models in Gazebo, but that doesn't mean someone has one floating around out there.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0